# I got err `Cannot find module 'react' from 'makeStyles.js' ` when I import a component in the test file

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

inside react src folder, I created `Tests/actions.test.js` and inside it I have the following code

```
import React from 'react'
import Enzyme, { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import Actions from '../components/actions.jsx'

// Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('Actions', () => {
      it('expect true', () => {
            // const warper = shallow(<Actions />)
            expect(true).toBe(true)
      })
})
```

the problem is I got the following err

```
● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'react' from 'makeStyles.js'

    However, Jest was able to find:
        './makeStyles.d.ts'
        './makeStyles.js'

    You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['web.js', 'js', 'web.ts', 'ts', 'web.tsx', 'tsx', 'json', 'web.jsx', 'jsx', 'node'].

    See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string

    However, Jest was able to find:
        './createStyles.d.ts'
        './createStyles.js'

    You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['web.js', 'js', 'web.ts', 'ts', 'web.tsx', 'tsx', 'json', 'web.jsx', 'jsx', 'node'].

    See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string

    However, Jest was able to find:
        '../elements/Table.jsx'

    You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['web.js', 'js', 'web.ts', 'ts', 'web.tsx', 'tsx', 'json', 'web.jsx', 'jsx', 'node'].

    See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:259:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../../node_modules/@material-ui/styles/makeStyles/makeStyles.js:14:37)
```

`actions.jsx`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import useElements from '../apiHooks/useElements'
// import useStyles from '../apiHooks/useStyles'
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import Button from './button'
import { useSpring, animated } from 'react-spring'
import Boxshape from '../hooks/Boxshape'
import Div from '../elements/Div'
import SimpleTable from '../elements/Table'
import '../css/style.css'

function Actions({ i }) {
      const { data, put, deleting, SetnewPost } = useElements();
      // const { GetByName, SsetPut, SsetDel, SsetPost } = useStyles()
      const [isover, setisover] = useState(false)


      const props = useSpring({ transform: isover ? 'scale(1)' : 'scale(0)' })
      function update(event, i) {
            put({ id: i.id, data: { text: `${event.target.innerText}` } });
      }

      function handlechange(e) {
            // SsetPost({ name: `${i.id}`, style: { backgroundColor: 'red', color: 'blue' } });
            // put({ id: i.id, data: { style: `${SGet.name}` } });
      }

      function onclick(e) {
            // SsetPost({ name: `${i.id}`, style: { color: 'red' } })
            // GetByName(i.id).forEach((Si) => setTimeout(() => {
            //       SsetDel(Si.id)
            // }, 0))
      }
      function Items() {
            return (
                  <div
                        id={i.id}
                  // style={GetByName(i.id).map(i => { return JSON.parse(i.style) })[0]}
                  >
                        {
                              i.tag === 'img' && <img src={i.src} />
                        }
                        {
                              i.tag === 'div' && <Div i={i} />
                        }
                        {
                              i.tag === 'table' && <SimpleTable i={i} />
                        }
                  </div>
            )
      }



      return (
            <div
                  id={i.id}
                  onClick={onclick}
                  onMouseLeave={() => setisover(false)}
                  onMouseOver={() => setisover(true)}
                  style={{ display: 'flex' }}
            >
                  <animated.div style={props} >
                        <Button i={i} />
                  </animated.div>
                  <Boxshape Items={Items} i={i} />
            </div >
      )
}
export default Actions;
```

- note: I never created a file called `makeStyles.js`
- note: it is work very fine in case I removed `import Actions from '../components/actions.jsx'` from the code.
- Note: it says `or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['web.js', 'js', 'web.ts', 'ts', 'web.tsx', 'tsx', 'json', 'web.jsx', 'jsx', 'node'].` I have no idea where is or what is 'moduleFileExtensions'.

Comment: did you import React in your module `actions.jsx`?

Comment: yest `import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While using Jest as a test runner for my my React (with TypeScript) app which uses Material UI, I experienced your exact same challenge with an identical error message.

I overcame it by installing styles:

```
npm install --save @material-ui/styles
```

If that doesn't fix it, try:

```
npm install --save @material-ui/core @material-ui/styles @material-ui/icons
```

Comment: not working, core and icons already present in package.json and just installed styles via yarn, but my react jest still gives an error about React not found in node_modules/...../makeStyles.js